# Dropdown menu for webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a simple website for practice purposes. I'm trying to create a dropdown menu for the Items in navigation but when I ran the website, it doesn't show anything. All files are saved in desktop.

Here is the code for my html(main.html) with jquery(jquery-1.3.2.min.js):

```js
function mainmenu() {
  $(" #nav ul ").css({
    display: "none"
  });

  $(" #nav li ").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({
      visibility: "visible",
      display: "none"
    }).show(400);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({
      visibility: "hidden"
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  mainmenu();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'lucida grande', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #fff;
}
#banner {
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #E3E3E3;
  background-color: blue;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#navigation {
  height: 60px;
  border: 3px solid #E3E3E3;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em #333;
}
#nav {
  list-style: none;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  display: none;
}
#nav li {
  font-size: 24px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
}
#nav li ul li {
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 3px solid #E3E3E3;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#nav a:link,
#nav a:active,
#nav a:visited {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav a:hover {
  color: lightblue;
}
#content_area {
  float: left;
  width: 750px;
  height: 382px;
  margin: 20px 0px 20px 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #E3E3E3;
}
#sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 250px;
  height: 402px;
  margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
  border: 3px solid #E3E3E3;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#footer {
  clear: both;
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="banner">

  </div>

  <div id="navigation">
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Items</a>
      </li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">T-Shirt</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Pants</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Accessories</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <li><a href="#">Shop</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="content_area">


  </div>

  <div id="sidebar">

  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <p>All rights reserved</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is the error in the console? FYI: running files off the file protocol is a bad idea.

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient version of jQuery?

Comment: @epascarello 8 - I've already tried this in visual studio 2015 and there are no errors. dropdown menu just won't show up. I've tried now transferring it to just sublime text, thinking that maybe there's something in visual studio that is causing the problem. It's still the same result so I'm guessing maybe its in my code. I just can't find.

Comment: OH..... the ul is not in the li...

Comment: The `<ul>` that contains the menu items is not a child of the `<li>` with the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the error is inside your code. You are trying to target the first ul inside the li but in your code you the ul is standalone/ outside the li.

```
<li><a href="#">Items</a>
  </li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">T-Shirt</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Pants</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Accessories</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

see the ul is out side the Items li, put it inside and it will work like this.

```
<li><a href="#">Items</a>      
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">T-Shirt</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Pants</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Accessories</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
```

You were putting a ul inside a ul directly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your jQuery but with the HTML, you should wrap your dropdown menu (ul) with items (li)

```js
function mainmenu() {
  $(" #nav ul ").css({
    display: "none"
  });

  $(" #nav li ").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({
      visibility: "visible",
      display: "none"
    }).show(400);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({
      visibility: "hidden"
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  mainmenu();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'lucida grande', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #fff;
}
#banner {
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #E3E3E3;
  background-color: blue;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#navigation {
  height: 60px;
  border: 3px solid #E3E3E3;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em #333;
}
#nav {
  list-style: none;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  display: none;
}
#nav li {
  font-size: 24px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
}
#nav li ul li {
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 3px solid #E3E3E3;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#nav a:link,
#nav a:active,
#nav a:visited {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav a:hover {
  color: lightblue;
}
#content_area {
  float: left;
  width: 750px;
  height: 382px;
  margin: 20px 0px 20px 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #E3E3E3;
}
#sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 250px;
  height: 402px;
  margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
  border: 3px solid #E3E3E3;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#footer {
  clear: both;
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="banner">

  </div>

  <div id="navigation">
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Items</a>
      
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">T-Shirt</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Pants</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Accessories</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
        </li>
      <li><a href="#">Shop</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="content_area">


  </div>

  <div id="sidebar">

  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <p>All rights reserved</p>
  </div>
</div>
```